# how to use rust to return an opencv image to python?

Tags: python, opencv, rust

I am testing how to use rust and python complementary, but I don't understand how to use types that are not part of the defaults, in the case of opencv in python it uses a np.array as the type, in rust it uses opencv::prelude::Mat ,I have no idea how to return that as an np.array type, I am using the cpython crate the code of the library is

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate cpython;

use cpython::{PyObject, PyResult, Python};
use opencv;

fn imread(_py: Python, path: String) -> PyResult<opencv::prelude::Mat> {
    //open image
    let input_image: opencv::prelude::Mat =
        opencv::imgcodecs::imread(&path, opencv::imgcodecs::IMREAD_COLOR).unwrap();

    return Ok(input_image);
}

py_module_initializer!(status, initstatus, Pyinit_status, |py, m| {
    m.add(py, "__doc__", "This module is implemented in Rust.")?;
    m.add(py, "imread", py_fn!(py, imread(path: String)))?;
    Ok(())
});
```

and the cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "python_lib"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
name = "imread"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
cpython = "*"
opencv = "0.77.0"
```

I have tried using the documentation but haven't found how to do this yet, also I have tried searching it but I don't have the answer yet on how to return custom types. I know this use is not efficient, what I want to do in the long run is to use the parallelism of rust to do many operations over a big set of images quickly and return the images to python, since with python it takes a long time to do this, even using python parallelism, for what I have tried until now rust parallelism seems better and the calculations in between are definitely faster.

Comment: If performance is a concern, switching back and forth between languages is probably not the proper approach. Anyways you'll have to write some sort of conversion to convert between the `numpy.array` and the `opencv::prelude::Mat` very likely using some custom intermediate format that both Python and Rust understand.

Comment: in this case the bottleneck is the IO operations reading from the disk, yet I have seen that it is the way it is being read and the subsequent operations the reason why it takes so long in python, other libraries use c to do this efficiently.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/PyO3/rust-numpy , so, there are ways to do it directly if the rust package has the python types declared, i would also like to know how to do that part myself instead of relying in the packages, but it's a start

Comment: for reference, with my best effort I only can read 20000ish images in python in about 7ish minutes, in rust it took like 20 seconds to read 50000, the overhead of moving the result to python should be small compared to that time difference